# Delaying post-build Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, post-build-event

I have a Jenkins job which compiles and publishes our Java project to a JBoss server.  Obviously, the server takes time to start and deploy the new code.  I have a second Jenkins job that runs Selenium tests against the running JBoss instance.

I would like to make the second (Selenium) job be performed automatically as a post-build action from the first job (I have already done this), but I want it to be delayed by, say, 2 minutes.  The amount of delay time isn't important, but I can't find anywhere that describes how to delay the start of a post-build job.  How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the advanced project options of a project configuration, you can set a "quiet period" that does exactly that. Jenkins will wait the specified amount of time after a build has been triggered before actually starting the build.

Alternatively, you could have the JBoss server trigger the build (e.g. by calling a URL) once it's up and running. The advantage of that is what it would take care of cases where the JBoss server doesn't start for some reason.

You might also want to have a look at the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) which allows you to run builds of other projects as build steps. This way you could run the Selenium tests as part of the original job and fail if those tests fail.